# Palabras con longitud tres

Tags: sql, regex

Quiero hacer una consulta que me borre las palabras con longitud menor a 3, es decir en la frase `"alambre de puas 25 km"` que quede `"alambre puas"`, intenté este query pero no funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

```
Select REGEXP_REPLACE(columna, '( |^)[a-z]{1,3}$', "" ) as fin  
From tab
```

Comment: Con que versión de SQL estás trabajando? necesitas actualizar los campos de una tabla o generar un store procedure que te ayude a actualizar los registros de vez en cuando!?

Answer (score 1):

El regex que estás usando tiene varios problemas:

- Solo detecta letras minúsculas y no números.
- Detecta una sola palabra dado que debe estar al final del texto por el `$`.

El siguiente regex detecta palabras de entre 1 y 3 caracteres, números o letras (minúculas y/o mayúsculas):

```
\b[a-z|A-Z|0-9]{1,3}\b
```